# how to send mail using server-side language?

Tags: php, web-services, email

I know HTML & CSS. I am building a website. added a 'contact us' page. I am using free web hosting at this moment which runs a linux server. php mail function is working fine now..

What are the other ways in which an email can be sent automatically through a website on receiving users information?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Configure smtp in ini file

Comment: I don't have access to php.ini file on the web server where I am hosting the website freely..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest PHPMailer , compared with the php function mail() offers many more features

### PHPMailer - A full-featured email creation and transfer class for PHP

[image]

### Class Features

- Probably the world's most popular code for sending email from PHP!
- Used by many open-source projects: Drupal, SugarCRM, Yii, Joomla! and many more
- Integrated SMTP support - send without a local mail server
- Send emails with multiple TOs, CCs, BCCs and REPLY-TOs
- Multipart/alternative emails for mail clients that do not read HTML email
- Support for UTF-8 content and 8bit, base64, binary, and quoted-printable encodings
- SMTP authentication with LOGIN, PLAIN, NTLM and CRAM-MD5 mechanisms over SSL and TLS transports
- Native language support
- DKIM and S/MIME signing support
- Compatible with PHP 5.0 and later
- Much more!

Example

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

[Documentation](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library to send e-mails via your own SMTP account.

Sample code:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You give very little information about your server hosting environment, but the correct answer is to get the php mail to work. There are so many reasons why, that is is impossible to answer without much more information